# Object has no attribute 'points'

Tags: python, django

This is my class in models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User as defaultUser

class User(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(defaultUser)
    points = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=50)
```

And this is my views.py:

```
def home(request):
    username = request.user.username
    points = request.points
    return render(request, "index.html", {'username' : username , 'points' : points})
```

If i comment points i dont get any error, but when i use points i get this error:

> Exception Type:   AttributeError Exception Value:  'WSGIRequest' object
>   has no attribute 'points' Exception
>   Location: /Users/jacintofleta/djcode/points/points/views.py in home,
>   line 8

Can i have some help please? Thank you for reading.

Comment: Why did you think that defining your own `User` model would replace the built-in `User` model?

Comment: Im new with django, so what i should do to create my own custom user?. Thank you

Comment: In general you don't. Create a `UserProfile` model instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined `points` as a member of `User`, not `WSGIRequest`. Use `request.user.points`.

Answer (score -1):

Try to extend django class User

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User as defaultUser

class User(defaultuser):
  points = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=50)

views.py
from models import User
def home(request):
username = User.username
points = User.points
return render(request, "index.html", {'username' : username , 'points' : points})
```